# How to monitor a spring-boot service by creating a ServiceMonitor?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, prometheus

I'm trying to create a servicemonitor that will instruct prometheus to scrape the metrics from my spring-boot service, but can't find the right way to do that.

I have a simple micro service with prometheus enabled, [see github for source](https://github.com/sloppycoder/profile-svc)

I can run it locally, or deployed into openshift. In both cases I can see the metrics output from http://:/actuator/prometheus endpoint.

Since [Openshift 4.0 Developer Preview](https://github.com/openshift/installer) comes with prometheus and [prometheus operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator), I want to simply create a servicemontior object which will trigger the operator to create prometheus configuration that will scrape by pod metrics endpoint, but I can't seem to get it to work, despite trying various tutorials.

here is my servicemonitor.yaml

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: profile-svc-monitor
  namespace: openshift-monitoring
  labels:
    app: profile-svc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deploymentconfig: profile-svc
    namespaceSelector:
      matchNames:
      - my-project
  endpoints:
  - port: http
    scheme: http
    path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    interval: 15s
    honorLabels: false
```

After creating the object the prometheus console shows the rules for scraping has been created, but i can't see any pods. Under menu "Status" -> "Targets", it shows

openshift-monitoring/profile-svc-monitor/0 (0/0 up)

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `namespaceSelector` should be at the same level as `selector`.